# Error building DataAnnotationsModelBinder project to get the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am refering to the "Validation with Data Annotations tutorial" here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs for my database first MVC3 project. I downloaded the DataAnnotationsModelBinder project but having difficulty building it. It throws following errors:

Error   1   'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' does not contain a definition for 'DoesAnyKeyHavePrefix' and no extension method 'DoesAnyKeyHavePrefix' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\XYZ\DataAnnotationsModelBinder\src\DataAnnotationsModelBinder.cs 47  17  Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations

Error   2   Metadata file 'C:\XYZ\DataAnnotationsModelBinder\src\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll' could not be found    Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.Tests

Am I missing anything? I tried using VS2008 as well as VS 2010.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have some missing references, so you need to include the missing references in the project.
You can do this by right clicking the references folder and add them manually. (see image)

[Refrences - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BA91.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `DataAnnotationsModelBinder` with MVC3. The `DefaultModelBinder` class already contains all of the logic that was present in the `DataAnnotationsModelBinder` sample you have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a reference to System.Web.Mvc 1.0 instead of what you're got at the moment.